# How to achieve sequential execution of test case instructions?

Tags: automated-tests, testrigor

I've created a test case using TestRigor, but certain instructions in the test case are executing simultaneously, leading to test case failures.

[image]

The instructions are expected to execute one at a time but in my case it groups the instructions and execute them simultaneously.
I want each of the instructions in the image above to run when the preceding instruction executes completely

Answer (score 0):

The steps are actually executed one at a time. So the test is no failing because of that, there is something else. The correct command is:

**in the right bottom corner of the screen**

Also, if you click more details below the screenshot you can see if the IF statement is true or false. I'd recommend to check that first and see if testRigor actually identifies the conditional.